# How to make generic function using LINQ?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, generics

Based on information from [here](https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/06/02/deleting-orphans-with-entity-framework/).

I found how deleting orphans with Entity Framework.

```
public void SaveChanges()
{
    context.ReportCards
        .Local
        .Where(r => r.Student == null)
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(r => context.ReportCards.Remove(r));

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I was wondering how to make generic function for this part because it might be used often:

```
context.ReportCards
        .Local
        .Where(r => r.Student == null)
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(r => context.ReportCards.Remove(r));
```

I thought about something like this:

```
public void SaveChanges()
{
   RemoveOrphans(Student, ReportCards) 
   context.SaveChanges();
}

private void RemoveOrphans<T>(T sourceContext, T orphan)
{    
    context.orphan
        .Local
        .Where(r => r.sourceContext == null)
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(r => context.orphan
        .Remove(r));
}
```

But of course it doesn't work. Any advice?

Comment: For the `Where` part just pass in a `Predicate`

Comment: You probably want to use `context.Set<T>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write extension method which does the same:

```
public static void RemoveOrphans<TEntity>(this IDbSet<TEntity> entities,
    Func<TEntity, bool> orphanPredicate)
    where TEntity: class
{
    entities.Local.Where(orphanPredicate).ToList().ForEach(e => entities.Remove(e));
}
```

And use it this way

```
context.ReportCards.RemoveOrphans(r => r.Student == null);
context.SaveChanges();
```

You can also use simple generic method which accepts `IDbSet<TEntity>` as first parameters, but it will not be such readable

```
RemoveOrphans(context.ReportCards, r => r.Student == null);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: `.ToList()` is not lazy. Using `.AsEnumerable()` and write a `foreach` loop.

Comment: @Oliver you will get `InvalidOperationException` in that case - you are not allowed to modify collection which is enumerated

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
private void RemoveOrphans<T>(Predicate<T> where)
{
    var items = context.Set<T>().Where(where).ToList();
    if (items != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            context.Set<T>().Remove(item);
        }
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Usage:

```
RemoveOrphans<ReportCards>(r => r.Student == null);
```

Comment: `items` can never be `null` (but empty). So the null check is not needed.